# Is it possible to create a unified diff in accurev

Tags: version-control, accurev

Is it possible to create a unified diff of two streams by accurev tools in CLI?

Anyway I can use a regular diff between two workspaces, but it is a kind of overhead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to diff two streams in AccuRev, here is how via the cli.

Compare all file versions in two streams:

accurev diff -a -i -v "stream-1" -V "stream-2" [ -cwW ]

Comment: Yes, but `-i` will give me only list of files that are different. I need a diff itself.

Comment: If you remove the -i option does that not give you what you are looking for?